# bash: run application in different consoles and use a variable for params?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm using Ubuntu 16.4.

How do I run an executable in separate consoles, where args for my executable are partially a variable? I tried the following code in an *.sh file, but it just blinks the console and exits.

```
#!/bin/bash

topology_path="./example_topology2/"

gnome-terminal -x bash -c "./ls_router 1 " $topology_path "testinitcost1 log1.txt; exec bash"
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "./ls_router 2 " $topology_path "testinitcost2 log2.txt; exec bash"
```

if I remove the variable, the separate consoles start up and I can see the application working

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "./ls_router 0 ./example_topology/testinitcost0 log0.txt; exec bash"
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "./ls_router 255 ./example_topology/testinitcost255 log255.txt; exec bash"
```

Comment: Just generate a single string instead of splitting it in three parts: "./ls_router 2 ${topology_path}testinitcost2 log2.txt; exec bash"

Comment: Thank you, this helped.